# Django primary key AutoField does not update when creating an object with explicit id

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Suppose I have a model A in Django that uses the default primary key AutoField. Due to a transition process, I have created some objects of A with an explicit id, using `A.objects.create(id=legacy_id)`. Coincidentally, these legacy ids start from 1.

Then, when trying to create new objects **without** setting an explicit id, Django gives the error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "topics_reply_pkey"` . It seems it is trying to create the object from id=1.

If I added 20 objects with ids from 1 to 20, I expect that when using `A.objects.create` without an explicit pk, it would create the object with id 21. Why is this problem happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Because the AutoField is a default value which means it only automatically increments in the absence of a supplied `id`.

Comment: Actually, I tried your code, and it works fine - that is, I created 20 objects using `for x in range(20): A.objects.create(id=x)` and then did `A.objects.create()`, and the id for that last one was `21`.  It *might* depend on the database you use (mysql, postgres, sqlite, etc).  Showing more specifics might help (the `A` class, and how you created the legacy objects, etc...

Comment: That's awkward, I am using PostgreSQL. Anyway, I've managed to solve it, but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by running the following command after creating the objects with explicit id.

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     cursor.execute(
        "SELECT setval('{table_name}_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id) FROM {table_name}) + 1, 1), false);")
```